# Connect to database through docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I know this is a question with lots of answers here, but none of what I tried solved my issue.
I'm creating a test databasae using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB training_db
COPY create_test_database.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

```
docker build -t my-postgres-image .
```

```
docker run -d --name training-db my-postgres-image
```

```
docker start training-db
```

Once that has been created and started, I can access it through dbeaver, but not from another project, which Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM 613615412341.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/cv-image:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV TZ=Europe/Minsk
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        python3-dev \
        python3-tk \
        python3-pip \
        libglib2.0-0\
        libsm6 \
        postgresql-server-dev-all \
        postgresql-common \
        openssh-client \
        libxext6 \
        nano \
        pkg-config \
        rsync \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get autoremove && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt update && apt install -y git pkg-config libgl1-mesa-glx tcl libopencv-dev python-opencv

RUN pip3 install  --upgrade  setuptools
RUN pip3 install numpy
ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt && rm /requirements.txt

ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

RUN echo $(ip -4 route list match 0/0 | cut -d' ' -f3)
```

Using docker-compose:

```
  version: '2.3'
  services:
    training_pipeline:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.service
      runtime: nvidia
      environment:
        - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-2
        - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
        - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}

      network_mode: host
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      entrypoint: ["python3", "main.py"]
   training-db:
     image: postgres
     environment:
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
       POSTGRES_USER: postgres
       POSTGRES_DB: training_db
     volumes:
       - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  volumes:
    postgres:
```

However, I keep getting:

```
training_pipeline_1  |     args.func(args)  # call the default function
training_pipeline_1  |   File "/code/functions.py", line 46, in label_batch
training_pipeline_1  |     pre_labeling = PreLabeling(site, connection_config, detector_config)
training_pipeline_1  |   File "/code/pre_label/label.py", line 43, in __init__
training_pipeline_1  |     connection_config, set_isolation_level=True, set_profiles=True
training_pipeline_1  |   File "/code/helpers/data_base_connection.py", line 37, in __init__
training_pipeline_1  |     database=config["database"],
training_pipeline_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
training_pipeline_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
training_pipeline_1  | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
training_pipeline_1  |  Is the server running on host "172.17.0.1" and accepting
training_pipeline_1  |  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is a snippet of my data connector class (skipping unnecessary methods):

```
import logging
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional

import psycopg2




class DataBaseConnection:
    """
    Class to perform transactions with training database.
    """


    def __init__(
        self,
        config: dict,
    ):
        """
        Args:
            config: configuration file to connect to the database where annotations are stored.
        """
        self._connection = psycopg2.connect(
            user=config["user"],
            password=config["password"],
            host=config["host"],
            port=config["port"],
            database=config["database"],
        )
        self._cursor = None
        self._next = None

if __name__=="__main__":
    config = {
       "database": "training_db",
       "host": "172.17.0.1",
       "password": "postgres",
       "port": 5432,
       "user": "postgres"
    }
    data_connector: DataBaseConnection = DataBaseConnection(
        config
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you have 2 containers

- One for the database (training-db)
- One for the application (training-pipeline)

Docker-compose allow you to run multiple container inside the same network and it does the magic for you. The simpliest way will be to update the docker-compose to include the database:

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  training_pipeline:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.service
    runtime: nvidia
    environment:
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-2
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}

    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    entrypoint: ["python3", "main.py"]
  training-db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres:
```

You can start the database with: `docker-compose up -d training-db`.
And, in python, the database will be available with the DNS `training-db`.

The other solution, is to create a network manually and run your container inside the network:

```
docker network create training-network
docker run -d --name training-db --net training-network my-postgres-image
```

And, in the docker-compose file, add the network as external (alias, not managed by compose):

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  training_pipeline:
    [...]
    networks:
      - training-network

networks:
  training-network:
    external: true
```

Comment: Hi @jmaitrehenry. 1st of all, thanks for your answer. I didn't get what you mean by "you have one container", cause I have two different docker files, as you said it should be in the first paragraph: one for the application and one for the database creation.

Comment: Ah true, I just see your docker-compose that only contain one container and the fact you install some postgres tools (like postgresql-common and postgresql-server-dev-all) in your docker image. I will update my answer

Comment: Yeah that it's not working either. Still get the same error.

Comment: @pceccon can you add a code snippet when you try to connect to the database?
And add the new docker-compose file to help you with it.